# How can i implement break statement in scala?

Tags: scala, break

I was trying to convert a java class into a scala one but I found problem with 
`break` statement into a `match case` structure.

Can anyone help me to do it in the right way?

Here is the code:

```
override def keyPressed(event: KeyEvent): Unit = if (Main.getScene.getMario isAlive) event getKeyCode match {

case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT =>
  if (Main.getScene.getxPos == -1) this setBackgroundPosition(0, this FIRST_BACKGROUND_POSITION, this SECOND_BACKGROUND_POSITION)
  this.setMovement(true, true, this MOVEMENT)
  //break

case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT =>
  if (Main.getScene.getxPos == 4601) this setBackgroundPosition(4600, this FIRST_BACKGROUND_POSITION, this SECOND_BACKGROUND_POSITION)
  this setMovement(true, false, -MOVEMENT)
  //break

case KeyEvent.VK_UP =>
  Main.getScene.getMario.setJumping(true)
  Audio playSound (JUMP_SOUND + Res.AUDIO_EXT)
  //break

case KeyEvent.VK_R =>
  Main.main(Array())
  //break
  }
```

As you can see,i would like to put a break statement after each case.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: match/case *is not* switch/case. There is no need for a "break" statement.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you don't need break statements in your example. If you ever need break functionality (for whatever reason), have a look here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/control/Breaks.html

Answer (score 5):

Scala's `match` will behave just the way you want here (it'll only match one case). You don't need a `break` after each case.